# how to add space between the label text and hint text here in code

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some help here. How can I add space between the labelText 'Name' and hintText 'Raakib Zargar'

```
Expanded(
             child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'abel',
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'eg. Raakib Zargar',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      teamName = value;
                    },
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: You can simply add space after labelText like this: `Name `. It will add required space

Comment: Adding a space will cause oddities if the user is using different system font sizes...

Answer (score 0):

You can set height on both labelStyle and hintStyle. This should add a multiplier to the fontSize for the text span of TextField's hint and label.

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
    ),
    labelText: 'Name',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      height: 3,
      fontFamily: 'abel',
      fontSize: 30.0,
    ),
    hintText: 'eg. Raakib Zargar',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(height: 5, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
  ),
),
```

[image: Demo]